# Use an alternate .clang_complete file

Tags: vim, clang-complete

The clang_complete plugin by default reads compiler flags from files in vim's `path` variable.  This is not necessarily desirable, since `path` is used for other purposes, and it means potentially having to tinker with the variable, track the location of `.clang_complete` files, etc.  It would be much simpler if there were, e.g., an option to just specify the files to include.

There isn't, but there's this:

> ```
> clang_complete-auto_user_options
> g:clang_auto_user_options
> ```
>
> Set sources for user options passed to clang. Available sources are:
>
> ```
>    [...]
> ```
>
> {anything} else will be treaded as a custom option source in the following
>     manner: **clang_complete will try to load the autoload-function named
>     getopts#{anything}#getopts, which then will be able to modify
>     b:clang_user_options variable.** See help on *autoload* if you don't know
>     what it is.

So I've specified:

```
let g:clang_auto_user_options = "clangcompl"
```

And created a file `autoload/getopts/clangcompl.vim` with a function:

```
function clangcompl#getopts ()
```

This function loads, but clang_complete doesn't use it and I get the error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>14_ClangCompleteInit..LoadUserOptions:
line   20:
E117: Unknown function: getopts#clangcompl#getopts
```

This is my first foray into vimscript, so any tips are appreciated.  Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the relative path, not just the file and function name, in the declaration:

```
function getopts#clangcompl#getopts ()
        let files = expand("~/.vim/clang_opts/*", 0, 1)
        for f in files
                let opts = readfile(f)
                for o in opts
                        let b:clang_user_options .= " ".o
                endfor
        endfor
endfunction
```

This will use anything in `~/.vim/clang_opts` as a `.clang_complete` file.